# Python - sorting/querying a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm relatively new to Python (2.7 import future) so please forgive me if this is a stupid question.

I've got a dictionary of `values[key]`. I'm trying to get the second highest `value` from the list, but write readable code. I could do it by mapping to sortable types, but it's confusing as hell, and then I would have to juggle the `key`. Any suggestions for how to do it cleanly would be much appreciated.

Comment: the second highest value from what list? Please post your relevant code

Answer (score 1):

2nd highest value in a dictionary:

```
from operator import itemgetter
# Note that this now returns a k, v pair, not just the value.
sorted(mydict.items(), key = itemgetter(1))[1]
```

Or more specifically, the 2nd value in the sorted representation of values.  You may need to reverse sort order to get the value you actually want.

Comment: `sorted(mydict.values(), reverse=True)[1]` ?

Comment: How do I retrieve the key for that value?

Comment: @cjm2671 - I've updated my answer to include retrieving the key as well.  While the shorthand is convenient, note from the other question you were linked to that this is `O(N log N)`, while an `O(N)` solution is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you also want the key associated with that value, I would do something like:

```
# Initialize dict
In [1]: from random import shuffle
In [2]: keys = list('abcde')
In [3]: shuffle(keys)
In [4]: d = dict(zip(keys, range(1, 6)))
In [5]: d
Out[5]: {'a': 4, 'b': 1, 'c': 5, 'd': 3, 'e': 2}
# Retrieve second highest value with key
In [6]: sorted_pairs = sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda p: p[1], reverse=True)
In [7]: sorted_pairs
Out[7]: [('c', 5), ('a', 4), ('d', 3), ('e', 2), ('b', 1)]
In [8]: sorted_pairs[1]
Out[8]: ('a', 4)
```

The `key=lambda p: p[1]` tells `sorted` to sort the `(key, value)` pairs by the value, and `reverse` tells `sorted` to place the largest values first in the resulting list.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
maximum, max_key = None, None
second, second_key = None, None
for key, value in dictionary.iteritems():
  if maximum < value:
     second = maximum
     second_key = max_key
     maximum = value
     maxi_key = second_key
```